# sp_MSforeachtable Abuse (Modification needed)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, code-injection, sp-msforeachtable

Recently someone hacked into our database using `sp_MSforeachtable`, so multiline query if im right.

Now my question is how i can modify `sys.sp_MSforeachtable`, he is using `@command1` and other commands to execute a query in order to drop our tables.

```
XXXX=Censored db name
(Somehow also spaces in front of the USE)
 USE XXXX;  
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all";
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "DROP TABLE ?"
```

Then my SQL Profiler shows:

```
select @mscat = ltrim(str(convert(int, 0x0002)))

exec(N'declare hCForEachTable cursor global for select ''['' + REPLACE(schema_name(syso.schema_id), N'']'', N'']]'') + '']'' + ''.'' + ''['' + REPLACE(object_name(o.id), N'']'', N'']]'') + '']'' from dbo.sysobjects o join sys.all_objects syso on o.id = syso.object_id '
         + N' where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N''IsUserTable'') = 1 ' + N' and o.category & ' + @mscat + N' = 0 '
         + @whereand)

declare hCForEachTable cursor global for select '[' + REPLACE(schema_name(syso.schema_id), N']', N']]') + ']' + '.' + '[' + REPLACE(object_name(o.id), N']', N']]') + ']' from dbo.sysobjects o join sys.all_objects syso on o.id = syso.object_id  where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, N'IsUserTable') = 1  and o.category & 2 = 0 

exec @retval = sys.sp_MSforeach_worker @command1, @replacechar, @command2, @command3, 0

create table #qtemp (   /* Temp command storage */
                qnum                int             NOT NULL,
                qchar               nvarchar(2000)  COLLATE database_default NULL
        )
```

Could anyone let me know how to secure these things? SQL Profiler is showing me the application name is PHP5, so probably register page or login panel injection..

Comment: The user that your website is using to connect to your database has too much access, reduce that to the minimum, security by exception!

Comment: Okay I've made a new user now, what permissions should I give it? Data reader and data writer? What permission does that give the website? It will be for sure DROP/DELETE commands are not gonna be used in the website for users.

Comment: Have you searched the Internet for "SQL injection"? You're a victim and you need to empower yourself with the knowledge to stop being one...

Comment: I can assure you our Anti-SQL Methods are pretty good, only thing is we have ran into some sql hacker, after 1.5 years this is the first SQL injection that was this advanced, other companies running the same system have no clue where its coming from and where the leak is.